# Sort a table with protected sheet

Tags: vba, excel

How can I protect a Sheet, so that a user can sort a table?

I have:

1. **Locked** the header of the table
2. **Unlocked** the cells in the table
3. Protected the Sheet with `sort`, `Select unlocked cells` and `AutoFilter` checked.

If I click on the button next to the header I can filter my table, but if I want to sort it... I get this error message:

> The cell or chart that you are trying to change is protected and therefore read-only.
>
> To modify a protected cell or chart, first remove protection using the Unprotect Sheet command (Review tab, Changes group). You may be prompted for a password

But if I unlock the header, the user can sort and edit it. Unfortunately, I don't want him to change the header, just sort the cells below. Is this possible?

Thank you very much in advance for your answers!

***edited**

Maybe it's only possible with **VBA** (added Tag `VBA`)

Comment: Apply Sheet protection. Unselect everything except `Use Autofilter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also looking for an answer to this for a while and unfortunately I don't think that it is possible without vba. Furthermore I don't think that there is an event fired by clicking on the filter/sort buttons in the column headers so you would need to add a button(s) which runs the following example code (needs to be adjusted to your needs):

```
Sub sortColumn()
'Unprotect sheet (Change "password" or remove it if you don't have any)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"

'Use Sort function (you can use the macro recorder to find the right code for other sorting/filter-options)
'Adapt Sheetname and Range of table to your needs
Sheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Sheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("A1:A10"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"

End Sub
```

An advanced solution could be to create a User-Form in which the user can select the column (s)he wants to sort and the sort-order (Descending/Ascending).